# how to show only horizontal gridlines of a grid in windows phone 7

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

I have created an grid with 3 columns and 4 rows in wp7. Now i need to show lines separating only the rows of the grid.(i.e I need to show only horizontal grid-lines of a grid) and also i need to change the color of the horizontal grid-lines. Help me.

Note: There is an way of using toolkit and we can achieve this through datagrid. but i want to know whether it can be done on the normal grid.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

border control can be used on each row to acheive this . border should be given with borderbrush and with required thickness...